# SCNLookAtConstraint, specify how the node looks at the target node?

Tags: scenekit

I have a text node. I am telling the node to always look at the camera node like so:

```
let lookAt = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: cameraNode)
textNode.constraints = [lookAt]
```

Before I apply that constraint the text looks like this: (see image)
[image]

If I apply that constraint, the node look flipped like in the image (see image).
So, the text does always keep that orientation and correctly look at the camera node, so the constraint is working.

[image]

I am trying to understand how the node "looks" at the target node though. I would obviously want the text to simply stay like shown in the first image as the camera moves around.

I tried to apply a rotation to the text to correct the behavior I get when applying the constraint but didn't work.

So, how can I get the text to have look at another node but not be flipped like in the second image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The documentation for `SCNLookAtConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint) notes:

> When SceneKit evaluates a look-at constraint, it updates the constrained node's `transform` property so that the node's negative z-axis points toward the constraint's target node.

But `SCNText` geometry is created facing forward along its *positive* z-axis, so your constraint system needs to account for that in some way. I advise using `SCNBillboardConstraint`, which is designed for this kind of case. [Its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnbillboardconstraint) says:

> An `SCNBillboardConstraint` object automatically adjusts a node's orientation so that its local z-axis always points toward the `pointOfView` node currently being used to render the scene.

With this, you shouldn't need to reparent the node.

Comment: The quote you put here explains exactly what I thought it was happening. I must have missed it from the docs. Thanks. I will try the pivot approach and let you know.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you figured it out with the pivot approach?
I'm trying something like:
ship.constraints = @[[SCNLookAtConstraint lookAtConstraintWithTarget:otherObject]];
    ship.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation([self degreesToRadians:180], 0, 1, 0);
To make the fron side of the ship always be rotated toward another object. 
It works until i apply the constraint...

Comment: SCNBillboardConstraint works perfectly. I did this: node.constraints = [SCNBillboardConstraint()]

Answer (score 6):

The "SCNBillboardConstraint object automatically adjusts a node's orientation so that its local z-axis always points toward the pointOfView node currently being used to render the scene."

```
textNode.constraints = [SCNBillboardConstraint()]
```

Comment: I've been using SCNBillboardConstraint for a while, when I posted this question I didn't see it (not sure they had it yet?), works great. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can also modify lookAt constraint by specifying the axis through which it will "look" via the *localFront* property:

```
let lookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: distantNode)
lookAtConstraint.localFront = SCNVector3Make(0, 1, 0)
node.constraints = [lookAtConstraint]
```

The above code will orient the *node* to *distantNode* via it's Y-axis.

Comment: This worked for me except, I needed to set the Z access to be facing front.
So SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 1)